# How to rewrite the URL using nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have a URL as 
https://test.rockon.me/Profiles/XYZ-ABC-PQRS/default.aspx
now using nginx i have to write rules for creating a subdomain which can make the URL as https://XYZ-ABC-PQRS/test.rockon.me/Profiles/default.aspx here XYZ-ABC-PQRS is the username of some user.

```
 server 
     {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/subcalls.log;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        listen  80;
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\nithinveer\.com$;

        location / 
    {
         proxy_pass http://192.168.6.190/Profiles/$subdomain$request_uri/;
    }
```

Comment: did u try this? rewrite https://test.rockon.me/Profiles/(.*)/default.aspx https://$1/test.rockon.me/Profiles/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, I have tried the same.
Unfortunately it didn't worked.
There is some logic missing some where in the code.

Comment: There is nothing an error but nginx is not configuring in proper manner.
The site is not turning up when we move to the users public profile.

Answer (score 1):

Yours not working, probably because you expect `$request_uri = /default.aspx` which is not, it is actually, everything after subdomain i.e., `/Profiles/user/default.aspx`

Try this,

```
server {
  server_name test.rockon.me;
  rewrite ^/Profiles/(.*)/default.aspx http://$1/test.rockon.me/Profiles/default.aspx permanent;
}
```

The other option using proxy_pass can be,

```
server{
  server_name test.rockon.me;
  location / {
    rewrite /Profiles/(.*)/(.*) /Profiles/$1/$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.6.190;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. :)